# Profiling Java char[] and Strings

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks, profiling

I am profiling an application and noticed that 52% (195MB) of the memory is being used by `char[]` and 20% by `String`. This is a large project with a lot of dependencies and I've just seen it so I have a couple of related questions to help me get started:

Does `String s = "some text"` create a char[]?

I've noticed there's hundreds of `String s = new String("some text")` with no apparent reason. Is this the culprit?

Comment: so, is it `new String("aa")` or just `"aa"`?

Comment: There's both. I'd assume there's not much I can do with "aa", but perhaps using new String("aa") is wrong and could be optimised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does String s = "some text" create a char[]?

This doesn't create any objects.

> I've noticed there's hundreds of String s = new String("some text") with no apparent reason. Is this the culprit?

This creates a copy of the String and possibly the char[] (two objects).  A copy is only taken if the String represents the substring of another string.

I would ensure you have a version of Java which supports `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`  This is on by default in later versions of Java and allows the JVM to use `byte[]` instead of `char[]` which can be half the size.

However, 400 MB isn't that big these days and buy more memory may be the simplest solution. You can get 16 GB for as little as $120.

Comment: (+1) Having looked at the JDK6 code, I doubt that `new String("some text")` would copy the `char[]`. I am pretty sure it would use the same array reference.

Comment: I'd be surprised too about copying `char[]`. If the immutable String is implemented correctly, this shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: `new String()` isn't necessary 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @LukasEder, The `char[]` can be copied, but not in this case.

Comment: @Peter: You're right. I just checked the source... Nice to know

Comment: There's 3.2 million instances of char[] and 3.19 million of String so Peter's almost certainly right. I'm using JDK1.5 (banks!) but will try 1.6 or 7 to see if there's any improvement (and update you). 52% is of concern not 400MB - I was testing it with a very small subset of data.